# On iOS and Xcode, how can initWithCoder be automatically be included?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, xcode-template

It is said that when a UIView object is created with programmer's code, then `initWithFrame` is the method to use for initialization, but when the UIView object is created with a NIB, then `initWithCoder` is used for initialization.

When a new subclass of UIView is created within Xcode, is there a way to make it so that the proper `initWithCoder` is created, because right now the usual method that is created is `initWithFrame` and I wonder if there is some steps in Xcode that I did wrong so it created `initWithFrame` instead -- could I have made it create `initWithCoder` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tweak your **Xcode template** file (for `UIView` subclasses) and put the `initWithCoder` method in - so that you won't have to rewrite it every single time.

If you want to know how to edit those template files, have a look at my answer here :

[How to change entire copyright notice template for Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097192/how-to-change-entire-copyright-notice-template-for-xcode/10097202#10097202)