# Xcode 5 - How to change copyright format

Tags: xcode

I have been looking for this answer and have found a lot of information for changing the company name, etc.  ***But only one that answered how to completely reformat this block of information.  Unfortunately the information is dated now and I cannot seem to get it to work.  The files I tried are locked.  Perhaps someone out there can tell me how to do this in Xcode 5?***

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PACKAGENAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
//
```

I would like to change the format to Java Doc style.  Something like this:

```
/**
 *  ___FILENAME___
 *  ___PACKAGENAME___
 *
 *  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
 *  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
 */
```

**Yes, I saw this and referenced it in my original question.**

***That is the only one that came close by showing how to completely reformat this block.  Only I think it may not work anymore.  I tried to change the block but was locked out of editing.***  Perhaps there is something I am missing for Xcode 5 or Apple has added a new configuration for this?  Still outstanding question waiting for an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change entire copyright notice template for Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097192/how-to-change-entire-copyright-notice-template-for-xcode)

Comment: Good and very common question. XCode keeps changing all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't edit the original, make a copy and put it in you own ~/Library folder in an equivalent path. Google Xcode templates to get more information.

Comment: Thank you for making it more clear to me.  I understand now.  :-)

Answer (score 54):

[image]

Coming from here - [How to replace the company name in the template headers in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132855/how-to-replace-the-company-name-in-the-template-headers-in-xcode)

Answer (score 16):

its simple in Xcode5

select project file from project navigator on the left side

then look at the right side utilities navigator, select file navigator

now 2nd group should be "project document"

- now overwrite "Organization" field

HTH

Comment: if you are still not able to get it, let me know i'll post the images

Comment: I found it, but struggled a bit.  Images would make the answer nicer.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your LaunchScreen.xib and update the text of that copyright label to whatever you like...